# How to use pytorch to perform gradient descent, and print out the true minimum?

Tags: pytorch, gradient-descent

I'm trying to use a gradient method to find a minimizer of a function `f`, where `x(k+1)=x(k)-α▽f(x)`, and `α=0.1`. The function `f` is `f(x) = 2*(x^3+1)^(-1/2)`, `x(0)=1`
Here is the pytorch sample

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch import optim

alpha = 0.1

class MyModel(nn.Module):
     def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          self.x = 1

def forward(self, x):
     return 2*pow((pow(x,3)+1),(-1/2))

model = MyModel()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(),lr=alpha)
terminationCond = False

while not terminationCond:
     f = model.forward(x)
     f.backward()
     optimizer.step()
     if x.grad < 0.001:
           terminationCond = True
     optimizer.zero_grad()
```

But I cannot output the correct value of `x`, how to modify my code in order to find a minizer of a function `f`?

Comment: There's a typo in `modef.forward(x)` I suppose? And the `forward` function would also need to be properly indented?! Also, how do you  prevent `x` from becoming negative during the optimization, that wouldn't be allowed, right? I guess you could try different learning rates if you haven't yet.

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55604691/how-to-use-autograd-find-min-max-point)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that need to be considered ...

1. For `x` to be a parameter (`model.parameter()`) x should be `nn.Parameter(torch.as_tensor([1.]))`
2. You are passing what (and why) `x` to the forward method?
3. The function `f(x) = 2*(x^3+1)^(-1/2)` is inversely proportional to x. When x goes up in value, the function goes down. The SGD will minimize the value of the function, hence maximize x.

> ```
> f(0) = 2.0
> f(1) = 1.41421
> f(2) = 0.66666
> ```

Here is a working example of minimizing f(x) ie maximizing x.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch import optim

alpha = 0.1

class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = nn.Parameter(torch.as_tensor([1.0]))
    def forward(self):
        return 2*pow((pow(self.x, 3)+1), (-1/2))

model = MyModel()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=alpha)
terminationCond = False
print(model.x)

f = model()
f.backward()
optimizer.step()
optimizer.zero_grad()
print(model.x)
```